# Name of the Facebook Graph API technology

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm new to web development. Reading the [Facebook Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) documentation, I found it quite interesting to use a unique URL for data query and Json for sending the data.

My question is: what's the name of this technology? I have worked with RPC and RMI in C and Java but this one is new to me. I want to learn more about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is REST? Slightly confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663927/what-is-rest-slightly-confused)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) or at least it is perceived as such. Traditional REST differs a lot - the facebook API is actually an RPC-over-HTTP API, but such APIs are now commonly called RESTful, although they are not, by definition.