# Where do I need to use JWT?

Tags: authentication, restful-authentication, jwt

The [structure and protocol](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-jwt-bearer.html) aside, I was wondering where JWT fits into client/server communication?

- Is it here to replace authentication and session cookies?
- Is it here to relieve servers of storing session tokens in a database or memory?
- Is it for clients to make sure they are receiving data from the expected server and if that's not a concern I wouldn't need JWT?
- Is it necessary or a good practice for server to server communication when the connection is HTTPS/SSL?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### What JWT is exactly?

It is a token that only the server can generate, and can contain a payload of data.

### What's the point of it?

A JWT payload can contain things like user ID so that when the client sends you a JWT, you can **be sure that it is issued by you**, and you can **see to whom it was issued.**

### Where can it be useful?

Usually, in [RESTful APIs,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663927/what-is-rest-slightly-confused) where the server must not use any sort of sessions.

### How does it differ from using sessions?

- In a typical session flow, the **browser sends a cookie containing a token**, which is **then matched at the server** to some data which the server makes use of **to authenticate the user.**
- In a JWT flow, **the token itself contains the data.** The server **decodes the token to authenticate the user only.** No data stored on the server.

### What is a typical authentication flow using JWT?

- User credentials sent to `/signin`
- `/signin` returns a JWT (signed with a key)
- JWT is stored in `localStorage`
- JWT is sent on every request (to API)
- The server can read the JWT and extract user ID out of it

Jwt contains the encoded form of the algorithm.data.signature and so if the user tries to fiddle with the user ID or any other data held in the jwt, then the jwt signature becomes invalid.

Jwt is encoded (not encrypted), so any one can read the data component of the jwt (see jwt.io for example). Therefore it is recommended not to store any secrets like password in the jwt.

It is also recommended to use an encrypted connection (SSL/TLS) when making the web request that contains the jwt because otherwise an attacker can steal the jwt and use it to impersonate you.

Comment: One of best answers I've heard ever.

Comment: Really? Do you store tokens in local storage??  https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#local-storage

Comment: @MohsenKashi An XSS attack is basically when foreign JS runs within your website. In this case, the XSS script gains equal permissions to your own scripts; Thus, be it stored in cookies, LocalStorage, SessionStorage, IndexedDB, or anything, it'll be possible to have the stolen.

It'll be next to impossible to protect a website while also being vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: @OverCoder Cookies with the `httpOnly` flag are not accessible through client-side scripts and thus are not vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: "It is a token that only the server can generate, and can contain a payload of data."

What means payload?

Comment: "No data stored on the server." You don't necessarily need to do that with cookies. Flask sessions do their own signing too so from my perspective, JWT is the same here. But I understand JWT is more its own defined schema at this point.

Answer (score 21):

[JWT](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token) is just a popular JSON based format of a security token.

JWT tokens are not invented to replace session cookies. They are mostly used to secure web APIs (request data). Session cookies on the other hand are used in web applications, where you log in a user and automatically send the cookies with each request (request pages).

JWT tokens are included in the Authorization HTTP header as part of the bearer authentication scheme. The main advantages of using bearer scheme authentication is that it's not vulnerable to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks because your script needs to explicitly attach the token to the request and can be used cross-domain (unlike cookies).

Bearer scheme authentication does require HTTPS connections as anyone who manages to steal the token can use it to access the API for as long as the token is valid.

Security protocols like [OAuth2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) use JWT tokens to secure APIs. OpenID Connect uses JWT tokens to authenticate web applications, but stores the token in a cookie.

Since JWT tokens are digitally signed by the issuer (server doing the authentication), they can be validated without talking to the server again. Digital signatures allow you to sign a piece of data (JWT token in this case) with a private key and the server receiving the token only needs the public key to verify that none of the data was changed. So the API server only needs the public key (which is not secret) from an authorization server to trust tokens it issues. The client of the API brings the token and the API server can verify it without talking to the authorization server.

Answer (score 3):

IMO JWT is mostly useful when the issuer (who generates the JWT) and the receivers (who verify the JWT) belong to different autonomous parties. Although it is possible, there is no need to replace authentication/session-cookie/token-storage/etc with JWT.

Answer (score -1):

You typically use JSON Web Tokens (JWT) for authentication and authorization in web applications. Here's a small point on where you might need to use JWT:

Authentication:
JWTs are commonly used for user authentication. After a user logs in with their credentials, the server generates a JWT containing information about the user (such as their user ID or username) and signs it with a secret key. This token is then sent back to the client, usually in the response body or as a cookie. The client includes this JWT in subsequent requests to authenticate themselves to the server. The server verifies the JWT's signature to ensure its authenticity and extracts user information from it to identify the user.

In summary, you would typically use JWT for authentication purposes, allowing users to securely access protected resources on your server after logging in.