# Differentiate between GET and POST method in Laravel Controller REST API

Tags: laravel

Differentiate between GET and POST method in Laravel cake Controller REST API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is concept of REST. REST is an architectural style and a design for network-based software architectures.It is not much specific on Programming language based.
Follow this thread.
[what-is-rest-slightly-confused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663927/what-is-rest-slightly-confused)

Comment: Thanks @Akhilendra yadav

Answer (score 0):

GET requests a representation of the specified resource. Note that GET should not be used for operations that cause side-effects, such as using it for taking actions in web applications. One reason for this is that GET may be used arbitrarily by robots or crawlers, which should not need to consider the side effects that a request should cause.

POST submits data to be processed (e.g., from an HTML form) to the identified resource. The data is included in the body of the request. This may result in the creation of a new resource or the updates of existing resources or both.

Answer (score 0):

GET - Retrieves Information (For eg: Providing response with some lists of data 
      from the database)
POST - Consumes provided resource and do the specified actions (For eg: Storing 
      form data in the database)

You can go through this: https://vimeo.com/17785736

Comment: Thanks For Your Affort @Prasan

Answer (score 0):

GET - Retrieves Information (For eg: Providing response with some lists of data from the database) POST - Consumes provided resource and do the specified actions (For eg: Storing form data in the database

Comment: Okey Done @vasant