# Why do we need Spring REST if we have Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-rest

If we can create REST Api using Spring MVC then why do we need Spring REST?

Spring MVC is based on servlet,is Spring REST also based on servlet?

Which specifications do Spring MVC and Spring REST implement?

And if we want to use only Spring REST do we need Spring Boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[spring-boot](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/06/spring-boot-simplifying-spring-for-everyone) is a project provided by spring community. It used Java Configuration over XML configuration and provide you default configuration in many scenarios.

For example, previously, you have to manually configure everything. Like DB connection etc.

But in spring-boot, in many scenarios, you just have to give the dependency name and spring-boot will configure it for you.

---

**Spring MVC and Servlets:**

Spring MVC internally uses Servlets only, so if you find any other java web project or framework, most probably, that would be using servlets internally.

---

**Now Spring MVC and Spring REST**:

First, you need to understand what is [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663927/what-is-rest-slightly-confused).

You can implement REST in spring MVC also, but again you have to do so many configurations manually.

[Spring REST](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) provides you already configuration, you just have to follow its rules and you could build a FULLY REST API.

[REST HATEOS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Spring REST project. The Spring REST part is based on Spring MVC. You do not need Spring Boot to create a Spring MVC project.