# How to understand JAX-RS?

Tags: jax-rs

I'm a beginner in Java and trying to understand JAX- RS API, what it does and how exactly it works, with no progress. Would someone please explain it with some simple examples?

Answer (score 1):

[JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) is a just specification that describes how to create [REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663927/what-is-rest-slightly-confused) service.

There are a lot of [implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services#Implementations) of JAX-RS like [jersey](https://jersey.github.io/), [restEasy](https://resteasy.github.io/), [apache-cxf](http://cxf.apache.org/), etc.. Each implementation may have some additional feature and expand specification.

Also thre are many examples of simple rest service. For example [1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) and [2](https://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/)